# User Generated Image for Open Graph from Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've been following the tutorial to create an open graph story [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share-using-the-object-api/#step3). Everything works nicely, but I'd like the uploaded image to be large i.e. "user generated".

My problem is in actually implementing that. Here's the code that gets the image from the SD card:

```
// If uploading an image, set up the first batch request
 // to do this.
     // Set up image upload request parameters
     Bundle imageParams = new Bundle();
     Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("image_for_facebook"));

     // Set up the image upload request callback
     Request.Callback imageCallback = new Request.Callback() {

         @Override
         public void onCompleted(Response response) {
             // Log any response error
             FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
             if (error != null) {
                 dismissProgressDialog();
                 Log.i(TAG, error.getErrorMessage());
             }
         }
     };
     // Create the request for the image upload
     Request imageRequest = Request.newUploadStagingResourceWithImageRequest(Session.getActiveSession(),
     image, imageCallback);

     // Set the batch name so you can refer to the result
     // in the follow-on object creation request
     imageRequest.setBatchEntryName("imageUpload");


     // Add the request to the batch
     requestBatch.add(imageRequest);
```

And here's the bit which subsequently gives the graph object its properties:

```
 // Set up the OpenGraphObject representing the book.
    OpenGraphObject book = OpenGraphObject.Factory.createForPost("books.book");
    // Set up the book image; if we uploaded the image, it is the "uri" result from the previous
    // batch request, otherwise it is just a URL.
    String imageUrl = "{result=imageUpload:$.uri}";

    book.setImageUrls(Arrays.asList(imageUrl));

    book.setTitle("A Game of Thrones");
    book.setUrl("https://facemash.biz/books/a_game_of_thrones/");
    book.setDescription("In the frozen wastes to the north of Winterfell, sinister and supernatural forces are mustering.");
    // books.book-specific properties go under "data"
    book.getData().setProperty("isbn", "0-553-57340-3");
```

What do I have to do to set the "user_generated" parameter of the image shown [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/adding-photos-to-stories/#publishing) to be true? (Assuming of course that I'm right in thinking that that's all I have to do to get a large image rather than a thumbnail).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the Scrumptious sample, in SelectionFragment.java, the getImageObject method. Basically, you need to create a graph object with the "url" and the "user_generated" properties:

```
    GraphObject imageObject = GraphObject.Factory.create();
    imageObject.setProperty("url", "{result=imageUpload:$.uri}");
    imageObject.setProperty("user_generated", "true");
    GraphObjectList<GraphObject> images = GraphObject.Factory.createList(GraphObject.class);
    images.add(imageObject);
    book.setImage(images);
```

Comment: That definitely seems to be along the right lines - thank you for pointing me in the direction of the Scrumptious sample. However, there seems to be an issue with the setImage() method. The setImage() method appears in both the OpenGraphObject and the OpenGraphAction classes - one takes a List<JSONObject> argument and the other takes a GraphObjectList<GraphObject> argument. For some reason, whenever I try to use setImage(), Eclipse gives me an error saying I need the other argument. I have no idea why, or how to fix it!

Comment: Ah - just realised the issue. A GraphObject like "book" in my code requires the setImage() method to take a GraphObjectList<GraphObject> argument. What's being supplied above by Arrays.asList(imageObject.getInnerJSONObject()) is a List<JSONObject>. So how do I achieve the same effect using the GraphObject?

Comment: I updated the code above to show you how to create a GraphObjectList.

Answer (score 0):

Ming's answer came very close for me. In order to attach an image to an `OpenGraphAction`, I had to do the following:

```
GraphObject imageObject = GraphObject.Factory.create();
imageObject.setProperty("url", imageUrl);
imageObject.setProperty("user_generated", true);
List<JSONObject> images = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
images.add(imageObject.getInnerJSONObject());
action.setImage(images);
```

Open Graph Actions have the method `setImage(List<JSONObject> images)`, but I couldn't find a `setImage(GraphObjectList<GraphObject>)` method. I'm using Facebook SDK v3.6, so that may have changed.

Comment: Hi @karl, your imageUrl is a local file? I'm trying to do the same with a local image and i'm failing all the time.

Comment: @TiagoPereira No, it's not. I haven't tried using a local image. Based on Ming Li's other answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/17411124/1139908, it looks like you have to upload the image to FB first, then use that URL in your GraphObject.